# Powershell script invoked by SQL Agent works differently

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a pretty simple powershell script (to convert .xlsx files to .xls) like below:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\MyFolder\*.xlsx"

foreach ($file in $files) {


$Filepath = Get-Item -Path $file
$NewFilepath = Join-Path -path $Filepath.directory.fullname -ChildPath 
"$($Filepath.basename).xls"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false #or false
$Excel.displayalerts = $false

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$Filepath".fullname, 
[Type]::Missing,$true)

$Workbook.SaveAs("$NewFilepath",56)


#https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx
$Workbook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
Remove-Variable Excel 
Remove-Item $Filepath
}
```

If I run this script from powershell directly it works just as expected. I mean for each .xlsx file it creates a new .xls file and removes given .xlsx file.

But when I invoke it by SQL Agent all the .xlsx files are simply *removed* with no creation corresponding .xls files.

SQL Job step
Type: Powershell
Run as: SQL Server Agent service account (checked folder permissioned and is full control)
Command: powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"

The job does not fail. But when I go to the step execution details I can see the following message:

Message
Executed as user: ServiceAccount. ...rors did not stop the script: 
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
 The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Sorry, we couldn't find . 
 Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?  '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
 The error information returned by PowerShell is: 
 'At C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1:16 char:1  + $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("$Filepath".fullname,[Type]::Missin ...  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException    '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
 The error information returned by PowerShell is: '    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException    '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '     '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
 The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.    '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
 The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'At C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1:18 char:1    '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '+ $Workbook.SaveAs("$NewFilepath",56)    '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
 The error information returned by PowerShell is: '+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
 The error information returned by PowerShell is: '    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException    '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull    '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"'. 
 Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '     '
 A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. 
 The corresponding line is 'powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"...  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

A `PowerShell` job step type expects a script but it looks like you are specifying the OS command `powershell -File "C:\MyScripts\MyConvertToXls.ps1"` to invoke the script.

Try a `Operating System (CmdExec)` job step type to invoke the command. Alternatively, paste the script into the `PowerShell` job step instead of running the external script.

Comment: Just tried with the step Operating System (CmdExec) and the results are just the same as above. With Powershell step it fails with "Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: line(8): Syntax error).  The step failed."  if I simply enter the script in step command window.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, and found this solution.
You need to create folder *Desktop*

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop`  for 32 bit machine

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`  for 64 bit machine

It's amaizing but it works